# migration of oracle apps form personilization

Tags: oracle-apps

Can we migrate a particular sequence of form personalization

eg: I have 10 , 20 , 30 ,40 ,50 Form personalization  in XX instance
and I want to migrate only 10,20,40 to another instance YY

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to migrate individual rules unless untill they fall under different level (form/function)